# ping script and log output and cut with grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to ping a bunch of locations but not at the same time, in order so they don't timeout.

The input is for example: `ping google.com -n 10 | grep Minimum >> output.txt`

This will make the output of: `Minimum = 29ms, Maximum = 46ms, Average = 33ms`

But there are extra spaces in front of it which I don't know how to cut off, and when it outputs to the txt file it doesn't go to a new line. What I am trying to do is make it so I can copy and paste the input and ping a bunch of places once the previous finishes and log it in a .txt file and number them so it would look like:

```
Server 1: Minimum = 29ms, Maximum = 46ms, Average = 33ms
Server 2: Minimum = 29ms, Maximum = 46ms, Average = 33ms
Server 3: Minimum = 29ms, Maximum = 46ms, Average = 33ms
Server 4: Minimum = 29ms, Maximum = 46ms, Average = 33ms
```

Comment: There's neither `Minimum = 29ms, Maximum = 46ms, Average = 33ms` ping output nor a `ping -n 10` command on Linux, but rather something like `rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.278/1.534/2.183/0.308 ms` and the `ping -c 10` command. Are you using `ping.exe` on Windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be able to solve this using `sed` two times and a `while` loop at the end:

```
N=1; ping google.com -n 10 | grep Minimum | sed -r 's/(Average = [[:digit:]]+ms)/\1\n/g' | sed -r s'/[[:space:]]+(Minimum)/\1/g' | while read file; do echo Server "$N": "$file"; N=$((N+1)); done >> output.txt
```

The steps:

- The first `sed` fixes the newline issue:

  - Match the final part of the string after which you want a new line, in this case `Average = [[:digit:]]+ms` and put it into a group using the parenthesis
  - Then replace it with the same group (`\1`) and insert a newline character (`\n`) after it
- The second `sed` removes the whitespaces, by matching the word `Minimum` and all whitespaces in front of it after which it only returns the word `Minimum`
- The final `while` statement loops over each line and adds `Server "$N":` in front of the ping results. The `$N` was initialized to `1` at the start, and is increased with `1` after each read line

Comment: When it outputs the line theres actually spaces before the word Minimum so it adds them in the output, there any way to cut it out?

Comment: I added another `sed` command which should remove the spaces.

Comment: Cool thanks. So if I wanted to like....add a name in front of the result like in my original post "server 1, 2, etc"  is that possible?

Comment: It should now do this as well :)

Comment: You should collapse the `grep | sed | sed` into a single `sed` script. `sed -r -e '/Minimum/!d' -e 's/(Average = [[:digit:]]+ms)/\1\n/g' -e 's/[[:space:]]+(Minimum)/\1/g'`

Answer (score 3):

Well, first of all, `ping` on linux limits packet number to send with `-c`, not `-n`.
Secondly, output of `ping` is not `Minimum = xx ms, Maximum = yy ms, Avrage = zz ms`, but `rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.953/5.970/5.987/0.017 ms`

So basically if you do something in lines of:

```
for server in google.com yahoo.com
do
  rtt=`ping $server -c 2 | grep rtt`
  echo "$server: $rtt" >> output.txt
done
```

You should achieve what you want.

[edit]

If cygwin is your platform, the easiest way to strip the spaces would be either what people are suggesting, `sed`, or then just `| awk '{print $1}'`, will trim your line as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed to remove first 4 spaces :

```
ping google.com -n 10 | grep Minimum | sed s/^\ \ \ \ //
```